# Missing selected value from RadioButtonList after PostBack

Tags: asp.net, postback, radiobuttonlist

First the page loads and shows an empty textbox and a button "GO"

Upon clicking the button "GO" a radioButtonList already in the page is loaded from a table based on the text in the textbox.

The radioButtonList is shown with new button "Made my choice".

The user chooses a button and clicks "Made my choice".

Upon checking for selected value or index the radiobuttonList is not checked at all...

That is it
TVM
Ricardo Conte

Comment: it will be better if you paste your code..and also tel me that r u using `IsPostBack` page property in page_load or not.

Comment: check IsPostBack set on your pageload. please show ur code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `Page.IspostBack` property into your `Page_Load` then Try to use it

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    // Your Code..
    }
```

into your `Page_Load`.Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     // Your code execute always

    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
       // Code which is execute without postback
     }


    }
```